# Unknown L1-COM connection and 2 gang 2 way switch wiring (UK)

Tags: electrical, lighting, smart-switch, uk

I'm trying to replace my 2 gang 2 way light switch with a smart one and getting completely lost in the current wiring and adapting it, I can't figure out why com would connect to L1 or find any examples of it online. Everything is COM-COM. Help identifying the current wiring would be extremely useful

**Current switch wiring:**
[image]

**New switch wiring:**

[image]

**Raw wiring**
[image]

**Current switch**
[image]

**Other side of the 2 way
[image]

Comment: Can you get us a pic of the back of the actual switch, focused enough to be able to read the labels? Not that I doubt your drawing, but, well, I've been known to work based on what I _think_ I see, not what's actually there...

Comment: @FreeMan I've added a picture of the current switch, thanks! Also updated the picture with wires in

Comment: Was hoping for a better angle of the "Raw Wiring" pic... Also, why does the "New switch wiring" show Neutral (blue) connected to L1, L2, L3 Line connection points? That seems like a recipe for a dead short and a breaker trip. I'll back out of this now, because I really don't understand anything at all about UK wiring, sorry I can't be of more help...

Comment: Can you get diagrams/pictures of the other 2-way switch & the ceiling rose[s]. Someone's taken the time to tag two of the wires, but it would be nice to know where they go… because as it stands it doesn't make a lot of sense to me either:\ BTW, unless it's a relatively new build, UK light switches don't have a neutral - it's in the ceiling.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've added a photo of the other side of the 2 way switch, but the roses (2 on one switch, 1 on the other for both switches) are so high up I couldn't get to them. The other switch is an absolute rats nest so I hope you can help me!

Comment: Eeek! Honestly, i would hardly know where to start on that. You need to get in the roses too & start tracing things with a multimeter. Only way.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: these are only guesses based on common wiring practices

It looks like your switch has one wired for 2-way operation and one for simple operation.

As per your top diagram:

- Left switch COM: This is your incoming live wire
- Left switch L1: This is the power out to the light on the 1-way
- Right switch COM: Traveller to the other end of 2-way
- Right switch L1: Traveller to the other end of 2-way
- Right Switch L2 Black: Traveller to the other end of 2-way
- Right switch L2 Brown: This is power out to the light on the 2-way

The 2-way circuit has been wired with the 'modern' style (https://www.sparkyfacts.co.uk/Wiring-Diagrams-Two-Way-Lighting-Circuit.php)

Your new switch wiring diagram looks to only allow for 1-way wiring, if you are happy with losing the 2-way switching, then connect as follows:

- the brown wire from the left COM to your new switches L
- The brown wire from the left L1 to your new switches L1
- The brown wire from the right L2 to your new switches L2

I would advise caution though because the other side of your 2-way is much more complex and I may be wrong.